# How to create UNIQUE constraint in SSMS 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012, ssms

I'm totally new to SQL Server, I use version 2012.

I have a table with the following structure:

```
Attendance
--------------
TagID     (FK)
SessionID (FK)       
ScanningTime
```

I need to create a unique constraint based on two columns (`TagID` and `SessionID`)

I'm not sure how to do this. I have created a query and tried this code:

```
ALTER TABLE Attendance ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    TagID,
    SessionID
)
```

But when I try to execute it, I receive this error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'UNIQUE'.

**What is the proper way to alter the table using SSMS? Should I create a query each time I want to do so?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were almost there. If you use the `constraint` keyword you need to provide a name.

```
ALTER TABLE Attendance ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_TagID_SessionID UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    TagID,
    SessionID
)
```

Or alternatively

```
ALTER TABLE Attendance ADD UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    TagID,
    SessionID
)
```

also works but then the constraint is auto named

Comment: Thanks, could you also answer my question in bold?

Comment: I would strongly suggest naming constraints - first option.

Comment: @jaspernorth - RE: Your bold question my preference is generally to avoid the designer and use TSQL but it is also possible to do this visually in SSMS through the [indexes and keys dialogue](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187019.aspx).

Answer (score 11):

If you prefer to do it via GUI instead of via `ALTER` statements, you can also right-click on the table in Object Explorer, select `Design`, then right-click somewhere on the empty background, and select `Indexes/Keys`. This will open a dialog where you select "Unique key" as the type.

Doing changes via GUI is a fast way for actions you tend to do rarely and hence are not sure about the syntax.

Many Management Studio dialogs - but not this one, probably as it is a sub dialog of the table designer dialog - have a "Script" button on the top left, which writes the action you are configuring via GUI to a query window so that you can save them for future similar tasks, or a copy and paste them, should you need similar actions.

Comment: After you close that dialog, constraint is not created instantly, but only when you save/close the table designer. Therefore, you can right click again on empty background and select 'Generate Change Script..." option.

Comment: @NenadZivkovic Your comment was really helpfull ;). I didn't think to click save after adding the constraint